# How to give dynamic user friendly url to specific page in typo3?

Tags: php, laravel, typo3-6.2.x

I'm a begginer of TYPO3.

How can I generate or define the routes similar to other PHP frameworks such as Laravel, Codeignitor, etc.

For ex. currently I can see the URL like this :
"http://localhost/typo3/index.php?id=3"

but if I want to make this URL custome like
"http://localhost/typo3/index/3".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension [`RealURL`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl) is most common solution for rewriting URLs in TYPO3.

You'll find large documentation and tones of snippets in the internet describing how to implement and configure it.